# Scala stack modifications on Function0

Tags: scala, stack-overflow, traits

I just faced very strange behavior in Scala's stack modifications.

Let's see an example:

```
class Base extends Function0[Unit] {
  override def apply(): Unit = println("base")
}

trait Modification extends Function0[Unit] {
  abstract override def apply(): Unit = { print("modified "); super.apply() }
}

val a = new Base with Modification
a.apply()
```

I expect the output to be like `modified base`.
Instead, I got `modified modified modified...` resulting in a `StackOverflowError`

What is interesting, that's happening only with Function0[Unit]. Function[String] is working fine:

```
class Base extends Function0[String] {
  override def apply(): String = "base"
}

trait Modification extends Function0[String] {
  abstract override def apply(): String = "modified " + super.apply()
}

val a = new Base with Modification
a.apply()
```

Output:

```
defined class Base
defined trait Modification
a: Base with Modification = <function0>
res0: String = modified base
```

Could somebody please explain this behavior?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like a bug because with custom `Function0` everything works as expected

```
trait Function0[+R] {
  def apply(): R
}

class Base extends Function0[Unit] {
  override def apply(): Unit = println("base")
}

trait Modification extends Function0[Unit] {
  abstract override def apply(): Unit = { print("modified "); super.apply() }
}

val a = new Base with Modification

a.apply() // modified base
```

Bugs should be reported here: https://github.com/scala/bug/issues

Comment: If you try to add `@specialized(Specializable.Primitives)` to your Function0 as in original scala trait, it will fail again. Seems like a bug for me. Reported.

Comment: Worth adding for visitors that `Function0[String]` is not specialized, so it avoids bugs in specialization.